Modelling of Amplifiers with Nonlinear Black-Box Models
I am trying to model the behavior of an audio amplifier through the Parallel Wiener-Hammerstein (PWH) black-box model that can approximate very well a wide range of nonlinear systems.
I performed the following measurement in steady state:

Input: two tones of the same level and phase, with frequencies f1 = f0 + df and f2 = f0 - df. f0 is at the center of the working band (1 KHz or more) and df few Hz (1, 2 or 4 Hz).

Ouput: I measure with high precision the intermodulation products that are created at the frequencies f0 + n * df and f0 - n * df, with n = 3, 5, 7, ... which also represents their order.


Now, the PWH model predicts that the products at the pairs of frequencies (f0 + n * df, f0 - n * df) are of "similar" value, since df << f0. Well, from the measurements of more amplifiers it appears that these values assume almost the same values in the module (generally differ in fractions of dB), but the phases are opposite!
It would seem that the (powerful) PWH model is not able to model the behavior of an audio amplifier.
Does anyone know how to explain the reason for this (conspicuous) discrepancy?

bit hard to know what goes wrong when we don't see how your model looks like in detail, and how you're fitting it

You're right Marcus. The model is the "classic" PWH, therefore: the input is processed by r parallel branches, where in each there are two linear time invariant (LTI) blocks in cascade between which is located a nonlinear memory-less block represented by a polynomial of n degree. The results of the r branches are added to compose the output. The fitting method is not important, since I am referring to the steady-state behaviour of any model of this type (then any r, n, LTI transfer functions or polynomials) on the described signal, and not to how the model is identified.

well, your fitting seems to lead to a model that outputs a signal of inverted phase, so we need to start looking at what precisely happens. Can't debug from 11 km high, need to actually look at the things.
